# JavaScript toLowerCase() method returns an error in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert all characters in a search field to lower case in my react app using the `toLowerCase()` method but gives the error `typeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.`

```js
onSearchChange = (event) => {
  const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
    return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't including enough information to solve the issue, but here's my best guess:

Your `robots.name.toLowerCase()` should be `robot.name.toLowerCase()` instead (note the missing `s` on `robot`).

You're attempting to read the `name` property off the array you're filtering on rather than the current element that's being operated on.

My recommendation for when you run across errors like this in the future is to check your error log for something like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at <myFunction>:1:27
```

This would read as `TypeError in "myFunction" function at line 1, column (character) 27`. You'd then be able to pinpoint exactly where your error is coming from. If you're still stuck, it's useful info to post along with your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I missed out ''s'' in the robot argument passed into the filter method.

Answer (score 1):

```
const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
})
```

I think this is just typo.
Replace 'robots' with 'robot'

Comment: Thank you, I missed out ''s'' in the robot argument passed into the filter method